# When data is ingested as HTTP POST messages, what are the options to receive the data, process it and write to HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

We are receiving data as HTTP POST messages from a number of servers. We want to receive the messages, do some pre-processing and then write it to HDFS. What are the best options to operate on real time data streams?

Some options i have read: Flume, Kafka, Spark streaming. How to connect the pieces?

Comment: The question is far too general. For getting the data from the source to HDFS, think Flume or Kafka, or maybe NiFi.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say because it's too general question. I can briefly describe our pipeline because we do the exact same thing. We have a few NodeJS HTTP server, they send all incoming requests to Kafka. Then we use [Samza](http://samza.apache.org/) to preprocess the data. Samza reads the messages from Kafka and writes it back to Kafka (to another topic). Finally we use [Camus](https://github.com/linkedin/camus) to transfer data from Kafka to HDFS (Camus is deprecated by now). You can also use [Kafka Connect](http://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-build-a-scalable-etl-pipeline-with-kafka-connect) to transfer data from Kafka to HDFS.

Both Samza and Kafka are (or were) LinkedIn projects thus it's easy to setup this architecture and Samza takes advantages of some Kafka features.